# Google font not recognized because name begins with a color

Tags: css

I have a slight issue with my CSS file. I am importing a Google font at the top of my CSS, but the font name begins with "Black". So when I go to use the font in `font-family`, the CSS identify's it as a color and not the font.

Is there a way to correct this?

**CSS File:**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Black+Han+Sans');

.home-header h1{
    font-family: Black Hans Sans;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a typo in your `font-family`, it's Black **Han** Sans, not Han**s**.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Black+Han+Sans');

.home-header h1 {
    font-family: Black Han Sans;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-header">
  <h1>Black Han Sans</h1>
</div>
```

Otherwise, you can also wrap the family name in quotation marks.

And this is also *good practice* according to MDN:

> It is a good practice to quote font family names that contain white space, digits, or punctuation characters other than hyphens.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family#valid_family_names

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Black+Han+Sans');

.home-header h1 {
    font-family: "Black Han Sans";
}
```

```html
<div class="home-header">
  <h1>Black Han Sans</h1>
</div>
```